# Extra pixel in before and after pseudo elements

Tags: html, css, background-image, pseudo-element, absolute

I'm trying to create a background effect using before and after pseudo elements by making it one pixel taller and wider than the actual element, but it always seems to have one extra pixel to the right or left. This only happens when the browsers is maximized (Firefox, Chrome and Edge), but does not happen when the browser has a smaller width.

```css
*, *::before, *::after{ box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #111;
}

img {
    max-width: 300px;
    display: block;
    padding: 4px;
}

.main-box {
    position: relative;
}

.img-box {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #000;
}

.img-box::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: -1px;
    right: -1px;
    bottom: -1px;
    filter: blur(10px);
    z-index: -2;
}

.img-box::after{
    content: '';              
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: -1px;
    right: -1px;
    bottom: -1px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.img-box::before, .img-box::after{
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #ff0000, #111, #0000ff);
    opacity: 0.7;
    transition: opacity ease-out 150ms;
}

.main-box:hover .img-box::after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-box">
   <div class="img-box"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png" alt="keyboard"></div>
</div>
```

It's not quite clear in the picture, but in the browser all sides of the background-image is 1px more except for the left side where it's 2px more.

OUTPUT: [Thicker line on the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HS00A.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like antialiasing. I guess you have either your browser's either your OS's zoom level set to something else than 100%.

Some browsers will try to round the positionning, but at some zoom level, this can't be done properly and you'll end up having one side floored and the other ceiled.

To circumvent this, you can use the `translate` property which should allow proper antialiasing to kick in (it will be blurry, but of the same size).

```css
*, *::before, *::after{ box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #111;
}

img {
    max-width: 300px;
    display: block;
    padding: 4px;
}

.main-box {
    position: relative;
}

.img-box {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #000;
}

.img-box::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: calc( 100% + 2px );
    height: calc( 100% + 2px );
    transform: translate(-1px,-1px);
    filter: blur(10px);
    z-index: -2;
}

.img-box::after{
    content: '';              
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: calc( 100% + 2px );
    height: calc( 100% + 2px );
    transform: translate(-1px,-1px);
    z-index: -1;
}

.img-box::before, .img-box::after{
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #ff0000, #111, #0000ff);
    opacity: 0.7;
    transition: opacity ease-out 150ms;
}

.main-box:hover .img-box::after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-box">
   <div class="img-box"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png" alt="keyboard"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. Just to make sure that I've understood it properly, using position to define the size of the element might cause some rounding and anti-aliasing issues, whereas using width, height, and transform won't, since the size gets hard-coded (for the lack of a better term). Am I right?

Comment: When using `top` and `left` some browsers will try to round the actual value to the closest pixel boundary, so that there is no antialiasing (it's also convenient for avoid messing with the rest of the page's layout). With some zoomings (e.g 125%) you may end up on positions where it will have to make the box bigger than it should be in an odd way (one side bigger than the other). When using `transform` the element will be out of the normal layout so browsers are ok to position it using antialiasing (+ it's rendered on the GPU as its own canvas layer). So here, there is no need to stretch

Answer (score 0):

I dont have enough reputation to comment.
I can confirm this solution is the only one that works.

It also works for two before and after elements where one has `transform: skewX(-15deg);`.
To make sure there is no 1px misalignment when zooming apply `transform: skewX(0.1deg);` to the other pseudo element. This makes no difference when viewing but is enough to take the element out of the canvas and apply antialiasing to prevent 1px misalignment when zooming.